# Smart Contract not Transferring balance

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I just started learning how to write smart contracts. I've been stuck on one thing for the past 2 days, I cannot get the contract to transfer the balance out once it ends.

Step 1 - Users send BNB to the contract to get into a draw - Working as intented

```
//An entry ticket is purchased when a transfer is received
receive() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= ENTRY_COST, "Insufficient BNB sent to enter the draw");

    uint256 entries = msg.value / ENTRY_COST;
    uint256 allowedEntries = entryCount + entries;
    require(allowedEntries <= MAX_ENTRY, "Amount of entries purchased are not available. Please reduce the amount or wait for the next draw!");
        
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
        uint256 ticketId = ++entryCount;
        potentialWinners[ticketId] = payable(msg.sender);
        emit addToPotentialWinners(ticketId, msg.sender);
    }

    totalPot += msg.value;

    //Add or for the time as well
    if (entryCount >= MAX_ENTRY) {
        endLottery();
    }
}
```

When the Max number of entries is reached (e.g., 10 entries) the contract will end. When I reach to 9 entries, everything was ok. On the 10th entry, I had to increase the gas limit from the issuing address for it to go through - i'm not sure why but I can troubleshoot it later, if you have an idea than it would be helpful to mention why.

Now after the last entry is submitted, the contract will select a winner which is being done correctly.

```
function endLottery() private {     
    uint256 winnerTicketId = random() % MAX_ENTRY + 1;
    winner = potentialWinners[winnerTicketId];

    //transfer only 80% of the pot
    uint256 transferAmount = (totalPot*80)/100;
    transferTo(winner,transferAmount);

    emit LotteryWon(winner);
}
```

As per Remix, the contract's balance now stands at 0.002 ETH, the entry number is 10, the total pot balance is 10000000000000000, and the winning address is selected.

Now the TransferTo function is set to be called, which is being done as I've added some flags that showed that it was called, however the recipient.transfer(amount) is not being triggered.

```
function transferTo(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
    //require(msg.sender == address(this), "Only the contract can initiate a transfer");
    require(amount <= address(this).balance, "Insufficient funds in the contract");

    // specify the gas amount to be paid by the contract
    recipient.transfer(amount);
}
```

If the issue is from the gas, at least the transfer should go through and show an error. My problem is that there is no log that the transfer is occurring. The balance of the contract remains the same. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AdamBoudj I want to transfer to the recipient (wallet address) the balance pot (transferAmount) as BNB from the contract's balance

Comment: can you try to transfer directly from endLottery, without calling `transferTo` function